# elasticsearch parse exception expected field name

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, range

I'm trying to filter some phrases according to range in a text field. I have the code but it doesn't work. How can I fix it? I also want to add must option to the query how I do that?

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
      "filter": {
        "range": { "date": {"gt": "2015-08-27",
"lte": "2015-08-28"}}
      }
    },
    "query":{
    "filtered" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "text" : ["has", "parti"]}
        }
    }
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to move up your `terms` filter into the top filter (i.e. no need for two `filtered` queries.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "text": [
                  "has",
                  "parti"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gt": "2015-08-27",
                  "lte": "2015-08-28"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that really works. Thanks.  I want to add phrase match for example ; the must terms has&parti should be searched as phrase like "has parti". How can I do thaT?

Comment: We should handle this in another question to not cram two different subjects into a single question.

Comment: No prob, glad to help.